# How to detect when conditions happen 3 times in a row having priorities?

Tags: r, python-3.x, categories, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have created the next minimal, reproducible example to simulate my problem.

I have a list of tibbles, 50 in this example, and I would like to classify them in four different categories.

To classify them I want to priorize the categories from 4 downto 1.

If the value 4 appear but it doesn't do it for 3 times in a row I want to see if the next time that the value 4 appears it happens. If all along the sequence it does not happen, then I want to do the same for value 3 and so on.

The problem with my code is that when the first value 4 doesn't have the lenght expected then checks the value 3, and if it is true I will not get the chance to classify as four a tibble that maybe has other values 4 with the lenght expected in further indexes.

I have used the `rle()` function to get the values and the number of times they appear consecutively.

I know that a bucles of for is not the best solution and probably there are easier ways to solve this problem without them and without `rle()`. A solution using python will be helpful as well!

```
valueA=replicate(50, tibble(floor(runif(800,min=1, max=5))))
valueB=list(list())
for (i in seq_along(valueA)){
  valueB[[i]]=rle(valueA[[i]]) 
}

cat=""
for (i in seq_along(valueB)){
  for (j in seq(valueB[[i]][[1]])){
    if (valueB[[i]]$values[j] == 4){
      if (valueB[[i]]$lengths[j] > 3){
        cat[i] = "four"
      }
    } else if (valueB[[i]]$values[j] == 3){
      if (valueB[[i]]$lengths[j] > 3){
        cat[i] = "three"
      }
    }else if (valueB[[i]]$values[j] == 2){
      if (valueB[[i]]$lengths[j] > 3){
        cat[i] = "two"
      }
    } else if (valueB[[i]]$values[j] == 1){
      if (valueB[[i]]$lengths[j] > 3){
        cat[i] = "one"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To clarify the problem I show the results I got in this case:

```
> cat
 [1] "two"   "two"   "one"   "three" "one"   "three" "two"   "two"   "four"  "two"   "three" "three" "three" "two"   "three"
[16] "four"  "two"   "four"  "four"  "two"   "two"   "four"  "three" "two"   "three" "two"   "two"   "one"   "three" "four" 
[31] "four"  "three" "one"   "one"   "three" "one"   "two"   "one"   "four"  "two"   "one"   "four"  "one"   "two"   "two"  
[46] "three" "three" "three" "four"  "three"
```

For the first tibble it says that is a category two but checking the tibble:

```
valueA[[1]]
  [1] 4 2 3 1 3 1 2 4 4 3 3 2 2 3 4 3 3 3 1 3 4 4 4 2 1 2 4 1 1 1 2 1 4 4 3 3 4 3 1 3 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 1 2 4 2 1 1 2 4 1 1 4 2 3 3
 [62] 2 3 1 2 3 1 4 3 2 1 3 1 4 2 3 3 2 3 1 1 3 4 2 3 1 1 1 4 4 1 4 2 4 4 1 4 1 1 4 1 4 3 3 4 2 4 2 1 1 2 1 4 1 3 1 3 2 3 2 4 2
[123] 3 2 4 1 4 3 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 1 4 4 2 1 4 4 1 3 1 4 1 4 3 2 1 3 4 4 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 3 2 3 2 2 1 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 1 3 2
[184] 4 2 1 1 1 2 1 3 3 2 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 2 4 1 4 1 4 2 3 2 1 2 3 3 2 4 3 2 3 1 3 3 2 1 3 3 2 4 4 4 4 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 4 3 2 3
[245] 3 3 1 4 4 1 4 4 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 1 4 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 4 2 2 3 1 3 1 3 2 2 1 3 4 1 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3 1 3 4 4 4 2 4 3 2 2 3 4 4 1 3
[306] 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 1 1 3 2 3 2 4 1 2 1 4 1 1 2 2 4 3 3 1 1 3 3 4 2 3 4 2 1 3 4 2 3 3 1 2 1 4 2 3 2 1 2 3 3 1 4 2 1 2 2 1 2 3 1
[367] 4 1 3 1 2 2 1 3 1 1 2 3 1 4 3 3 1 1 3 1 1 3 4 3 4 4 3 3 4 1 2 1 3 2 4 3 1 2 4 4 4 1 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 4 4 4 3 3 2 3 3 2 1
[428] 3 3 1 2 2 3 2 2 3 4 3 3 4 2 3 4 3 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 2 3 3 3 1 4 3 4 3 2 2 4 4 3 4 2 2 1 3 4 2 1 2 3 2 1 4 1 3 2 2 4 4 3 2 2 4
[489] 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 2 4 4 1 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 2 4 2 3 2 3 3 4 3 2 4 4 3 4 3 4 2 2 3 3 2 4 3 4 2 1 4 1 4 2 1 1 1 4 1 4 4 3
[550] 4 2 4 1 4 1 1 1 3 2 4 1 3 1 3 3 4 1 2 3 2 1 1 3 4 2 2 3 4 4 1 3 3 2 4 4 4 2 1 2 2 2 4 1 1 1 2 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 4 2 4 4 3 3 4
[611] 2 1 2 2 3 2 2 1 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 3 4 2 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 3 1 2 4 3 1 4 3 4 2 3 3 3 2 3 4 2 4 2 3 3 1 2 1 2 3 4 3 2 2 3 4 1 4 3 2
[672] 1 2 3 4 3 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 1 1 4 4 3 3 1 1 4 1 1 4 3 1 3 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 2 1 4 1 1 3 3 1 4 2 2 3 4 4 3 4 2
[733] 4 1 3 2 1 1 4 2 2 3 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 4 1 2 1 2 3 3 4 2 1 1 3 2 3 2 2 4 1 4 1 4 4 1 1 1 3 2 4 1 2 4 2 2 2 2 3 4 4
[794] 4 1 4 2 1 3 3
```

I can see starting at 619 value more than three fours in a row, so the real category of my first tibble have to be four.

Comment: In other words, for each tibble, you want the maximum number that appears consecutively the maximum number of times? Can you give the results you are expecting for you sample data set, or at least for the first few tibbles?

Comment: I am re-reading what you asked. You seem to be saying that you want to look for the value 4 and if it repeats at least 3 times consecutively you want to classify the tibble as a "4". If it doesn't, you want to look for the value 3 and if it repeats at least 3 times consecutively you want to classify the tibble as a "3". If not, you want to look at the value 2, and if it repeats three times you want to classify it as a "2". If not look at the value, and if it repeats three times, class as "1". What about everything else?  From your data set I don't see any examples that repeat more than twice.

Comment: It is the first time I try to do a min, rep example and maybe I have not contemplated all the possibilites. Theorically all of them have to belong to one of those four categories. I will try to implement your answer and let you know! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution even though is not elegant at all.

```
valueA=replicate(50, tibble(floor(runif(800,min=1, max=5))))
valueB=list(list())
for (i in seq_along(valueA)){
  valueB[[i]]=rle(valueA[[i]]) 
}

cat=NA
for (i in seq_along(valueB)){
  for (j in seq(valueB[[i]][[1]])){
    if ((valueB[[i]]$values[j] == 4)&(valueB[[i]]$lengths[j] > 3)){
        cat[i] = 4
        break
    }
  }
}

for (i in seq_along(valueB)){
  for (j in seq(valueB[[i]][[1]])){
    if ((valueB[[i]]$values[j] == 3)&(valueB[[i]]$lengths[j] > 3)&(is.na(cat[i]))){
        cat[i] = 3
        break
    }
  }
}

for (i in seq_along(valueB)){
  for (j in seq(valueB[[i]][[1]])){
    if ((valueB[[i]]$values[j] == 2)&(valueB[[i]]$lengths[j] > 3)&(is.na(cat[i]))){
        cat[i] = 2
        break
    }
  }
}

for (i in seq_along(valueB)){
  for (j in seq(valueB[[i]][[1]])){
    if ((valueB[[i]]$values[j] == 1)&(valueB[[i]]$lengths[j] > 3)&(is.na(cat[i]))){
        cat[i] = 1
        break
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of using else if inside the for loops, I use 4 differents for loops, adding a break at the end of their if condition.
By doing it I save time reading the whole loop if the condition has been already  met. The cat value is filled with NA's, so once one category with more priority has been detected this tibble will not be evaluated again.

I had to use the rle() function as originally posted.

Answer (score 1):

I created a function, then a for loop that runs the function. The function works on one tibble at a time. It uses the lag() function to look back 3 rows and if all the values match, it captures the matched value in the "repeat" field. I then filter out all values other than 1 thru 4 as you only seem interested in those values. Then I use summarize() to find the maximum value captured in the "repeat" field and call this "class". You seem to want to use strings, so I use case_when to convert the class value to a string. That string is returned as the result of the function. The for loop then cycles through each of the tibbles and captures the result in results_list().

In your sample data I do not see any tibbles that have values repeated consecutively more than two times. I found in all the tibbles, the value of 4 is repeated two times so a run that only looks back one row will return a class of "four" for all the tibbles. I either misunderstood what you are looking for, or your data set doesn't support it.

```
library(dplyr)

find_rep2 <- function(df){

    df1 <- df %>%
        mutate(repeat = ifelse(temp == lag(temp) & temp == lag(temp,2) & temp == lag(temp, 3), temp, NA)) %>%
        filter(temp %in% 1:4) %>%
        summarize(class = max(repeat, na.rm = TRUE)) 
    
    result <- case_when(
        df1$class == 4 ~ "four",
        df1$class == 3 ~ "three",
        df1$class == 2 ~ "two",
        df1$class == 1 ~ "one",
        TRUE ~ "undefined"
    )
}

results_list <- list()

for(i in 1:length(valueA)){
    df <- tibble(temp = valueA[[i]])
    results_list[[i]] <- find_rep2(df)
}
```

Comment: I have not been able to solve it using your solution. I had some problems with the repeat function but it is an interesting way to approach the problem so thank you for your time!